# HTML audio not working inside nested div containers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having problem playing audio in html. The audio plays well when I keep the audio tag inside a div container but it doesn't play when I put it inside another div. See the code for better understanding of problem

Case#1:(Works)

```
<html>
<body>
<div id = "buttons">
<audio src="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3" id="player"></audio>  
<button id = "prev">PREV</button>
<button id = "play" onclick = "play()">PLAY</button>
<button id = "pause" onclick = "pause()">PAUSE</button>
<button id = "next">NEXT</button>
</div>
<script>
function play() {
    document.getElementById('player').play();
}
function pause() {
    document.getElementById('player').pause();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Case#2:(Doesn't works)

```
<html>
<body>
<div id = "player">
<div id = "buttons">
<audio src="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3" id="player"></audio>  
<button id = "prev">PREV</button>
<button id = "play" onclick = "play()">PLAY</button>
<button id = "pause" onclick = "pause()">PAUSE</button>
<button id = "next">NEXT</button>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function play() {
    document.getElementById('player').play();
}
function pause() {
    document.getElementById('player').pause();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with your question, but `<center>` has been deprecated since the end of World War II.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? My guess is that there some invisible element over the play button that blocks your click event.

Comment: @JonasGrumann No, there are no errors on console.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle that shows the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @JonasGrumann Just run both the codes in your browser. You will see one works and other doesn't.

Comment: So you're too lazy to set up a fiddle for us to see the problem? Why would I have to copy paste all your stuff? You should do it for us so we can concentrate on helping you. Well I won't bother, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st `div` and audio tag id is same `="player"`.

So change `id` of 1st `div` as I changed it to `"playe"`.
If you want your audio tag to have `id="player"`.

Now this will work.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="playe">
    <div id="buttons">
      <audio src="test.mp3" id="player"></audio>
      <button id="prev">PREV</button>
      <button id="play" onclick="play()">PLAY</button>
      <button id="pause" onclick="pause()">PAUSE</button>
      <button id="next">NEXT</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function play() {
      document.getElementById('player').play();
    }

    function pause() {
      document.getElementById('player').pause();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was creating such a silly mistake. I almost wasted 2-3 hours on it. Thanks :)